# check if input field is empty with html5 and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

How can i check if a html5 input field is empty? I am trying to override the native validation message given by using a required text input.

This is how my code looks now:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        H5F.setup(document.getElementById("contact-form"));
              var name = document.getElementById("contact-name")
        if (name.value === "") {
              name.setCustomValidity("Please fill out the field with your name");    
        }


    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here what u need.. a full guide about how to change this native validation message :D
http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/demos/forms.html#Locale-Settings

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping your code in a blur listener should do the trick.

```
    var name = document.getElementById("contact-name");
    $(name).blur(function(){
        if (name.value === "") {
            name.setCustomValidity("Please fill out the field with your name");    
        }
    });
```

Comment: sorry, but it did'nt help, it just gives the native validation message given by the browser...